# ui-sref css incorrect on Safari

Tags: javascript, css, angular-ui-router

I have a boostrap navbar with white links on black. When I reload the page the links are black until I select them with my cursor which causes the white to appear as I slide. The problem is solved if I add a blank href="" attribute. However I would like to figure out why this is happening and if there is another solution.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
   <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

This solves issue:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
   <li><a href="" ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Attached is a shot of what I mean - I am slidig the mouse from left to right over the link.

[image]